# Generating array of hashes from RoR query output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails novice here. Say I have two tables, Owners (owner_id, name) and Cats (cat_id, cname). They're associated via a one-to-many relationship where an owner can own many cats but a cat can only have one owner. Given an input of owner_id, I want to retrieve the cat name and id for each cat owned by that Owner, and store it as an array of hashes (i.e. [{:cat_id => 1, cname => "cat1"}, {:cat_id => 2, cname = "cat2"}].

So far I have something like output = [Owner.find(owner_id).join(:Cats)] but I'm not sure how to complete the statement. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Owner.find(owner_id).cats will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Cat.all(:conditions => ['owner_id = ?', owner_id])
```

Or:

```
Owner.find(owner_id).cats
```

That one assumes you have `has_many :cats` in your Owner model. If you need a list of hashes instead of active record objects you can use .collect to transform your set.

Comment: Thank you! So this returns the data in the form of an active record object?

Comment: Yup. Owner and Cat are subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base and the methods provided by AR return instances of the class. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ has a great wealth of info to help you on your RoR quest.